# PHP client to communicate with Apache Thrift API

Tags: php, thrift, thrift-protocol, php-socket, tclientsocket

I am a PHP developer, working on a site that will be communicating with another server with Apache Thrift API, so I want to know that is there some existing class or some way that I can use to communicate with Thrift API in PHP. I saw example written in Python that use Tsocket but I don't know whether PHP has Tsocket class or not. So if some one have done such work then please post some sample or tell about some class that I can use to implement thrift API client in PHP.

thanks in advance for everyone's effort.

Comment: don't even know what to try, I was going to use simple PHP Socket class but in thrift API's documentation they have written that most of languages have this Tsocket class that I tried to find on php.net to know about its methods but didn't find

Comment: its right here: http://php.net/fsockopen

Comment: so this fsockopen is equivalent to TSocket of python, I should try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted in a comment, you should use [fsockopen](http://php.net/fsockopen), as it provides a low-level access to sockets, just like pythons TSocket.

Comment: I used this code: `<?php


//A struture
$up = UserProfile($uid=1,
                 $name="Mark Slee",
                 $blurb="I'll find something to put here.");

# Talk to a server via TCP sockets, using a binary protocol
$fp = fsockopen("localhost",9090, $errno, $errstr, 90);
# Use the service we already defined
$service=fwrite($fp, $up);

while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
}
 `  so is it correct alternative of python client code at : http://thrift.apache.org/

Comment: yes internatlly fsockopen is used but actually one should use this http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsagePhp